# Why does React/RCTAssert.h' file remain unfound even after fixing header search paths

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

[image]
I am literally stuck with this error **React/RCTAssert.h' file not found** ,I followed other questions suggesting that the header search path could be wrong for test target.
Hence I even deleted the test target

srcroot = /Users/shyamnath/Desktop/apps/xxx/ios

```
//:configuration = Debug
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = 
$(inherited) 
$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen/ios     
$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-device-info/RNDeviceInfo 
$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/React 
$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-aes-kit/ios/RCTAesCrypto/**


//:configuration = Release
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = 
$(inherited) 
$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen/ios
$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-device-info/RNDeviceInfo
$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/React 
$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-aes-kit/ios/RCTAesCrypto/**

//:completeSettings = some
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS
```

Is there anything visibly wrong with the header search paths that are shown above?
I tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it but nothing seems to solve it.

> The files under the project directory are as follows,
>
> android
>   index.js
>   package-lock.json 
>   app
>   ios
>   package.json
>   app.json
>   node_modules
>   yarn.lock

Could it be because the node_modules folder is not within ios?
and the srcroot being /Users/shyamnath/Desktop/apps/xxx/ios

Answer (score 1):

The same issue I had faced, Solved by adding the path to the Project target and Test Target.

`$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/React`

So follow the step :

**'AwesomeProject' -> AwesomeProject(Target) -> Build Settings -> Header Search 
Path**

```
`$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/React`
```

And add the above path as recursive if not there.

**'AwesomeProject' -> AwesomeProjectTest(Target) -> Build Settings -> Header Search 
Path**

```
`$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/React`
```

And add the above path as recursive.

I have referred to the [answer](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2454#issuecomment-135488208).

Hope this will help someone.